# Fix memory leak

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have the following function which gets called multiple times in my code:

```
char* get_section_name(const char* section, const char* value) {

  char *tmp = (char *)malloc(STR_LEN * sizeof(char));

  if(strlen(section)>0) {

      strcat(tmp, section);

      strcat(tmp,".");

  }

  strcat(tmp, value);    

  return tmp;

}
```

and I call it in other functions like this:

```
section_name = get_section_name(data->model_name,"params_default");
```

What is the best way to free this memory? Can I just call `free(section_name)` when I am done?

Comment: `strcat(tmp, section)` assumes `tmp` holds a string. It does not.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc - just saw this, was news to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `free`, however, you could consider a different name that makes it clear it is allocating memory. Also, you could make use of `sprintf` for combining 2 strings and `strdup` for just copying one.

```
char* create_section_name(const char* section, const char* value) { 
  const int sectionLen = strlen(section);   

  if(sectionLen>0) {
      //+1 for the period and +1 for the null
      char *tmp = (char *)malloc((sectionLen + strlen(value) + 2) * sizeof(char));
      //do that often? consider a newString(size) macro. See below
      sprintf(tmp, "%s.%s", section, value);    
      return tmp;
  }
  else {    
    return strdup(value);
  }
}
```

This assumes you don't need the full `STR_LEN`, it uses just enough in both cases.

`newString` macro I suggested:

```
#define newString(size) (malloc((size) * sizeof(char)))
```

Or it can even automatically add one for the null:

```
#define newString(size) (malloc(((size)+1) * sizeof(char)))
```

Then malloc is replaced with this:

```
char *tmp = newString(sectionLen + strlen(value) + 1); //+1 for period
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you must make sure `tmp`was actually allocated (ie `malloc`did not fail) :

```
tmp = (char *)malloc(STR_LEN * sizeof(char));
if (tmp == NULL) {
  // quit now !
}
```

Then, as you `strcat` it, you must be sure `tmp` is an empty string, ie its first character is 0

```
tmp[0] = '\0';
```

Then, yes, you can free it the way you wrote it.

One last thing : you have to be sure that `strlen(section)+strlen(".")+strlen(value) < STR_LEN`, or you will overwrite memory you're not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

`free` would be great here, but as an alternative, might be the best way to do this would be a change to signature. If you make it like

```
void get_section_name(const char* section, const char* value, char * result)
```

then you can pass a pointer to an allocated memory, so the user of this function is perfectly aware of how should he handle the memory after it's used.

Comment: That's a good point, indeed. Maybe then the function can return `void`, or some value to indicate something failed (the call to `malloc`, for instance).

Comment: Of course it should return void, copy-paste error, now fixed! Thanx @Fabien!

Answer (score 0):

Always perform error check when creating memory using `malloc()`,`calloc()`, or`realloc()`

Yes you can use `free` here

`free(section_name)` , Because `tmp`returned is stored in `section_name` which now points to malloced memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a leap of faith that `STR_LEN` is going to be of sufficient size. If so then `free(section_name);` will suffice. Bur use `strcpy` instead of `strcat` or initialize a null string.